# does Database.HDBC support named parameters?

Tags: sql, haskell, named-parameters, hdbc

I don't like relying on positional parameters, is it possible to do so with [HDBC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC)?

I could see passing `[(String, SqlValue)]` instead of `[SqlValue]` as arguments to the various executing functions of [this package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC).

In a nutshell, I'd rather

```sql
select 
  t.f1
  , t.f2
  , t.f3
from
  schema.table t
where
 t.f1 > @param1
 and t.f2 < @param2
```

than

```sql
select 
  t.f1
  , t.f2
  , t.f3
from
  schema.table t
where
 t.f1 > ?
 and t.f2 < ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with hdbc directly but i do it with the help of the shakespeare-text package:

```
quickQuery cn (T.unpack
                 [st|select bar, baz, foo
                       from table1 r
                      inner join location l on r.locat_id = l.location_id
                      where r.record_id = #{pageIdxId page}
                        and foo > #{var1 + var2}
                      order by 1|]) []
```

Notice haskell variables and expressions in #{} placeholders.

be careful with string splicing though.

use sql escaping function with string values.

```
sqlEscape :: Text -> Text
sqlEscape = T.replace "'" "''"
```

then

```
[st|update foo set bar = '#{sqlEscape someString}' where recid = #{myRecId}|]
```

Or if you are up to the task, you can take the shakespeare-text library and add a small change to it to automatically escape all isString types.

Comment: Thanks, that is an approach I didn't envision; I currently do it this way

declare (at)param1 type  
declare (at)param2 type  
  
set (at)param1 = ?  
set (at)param2 = ?  
  
... rest of the statement  
  
Issue with string interpolation is handling potential sql injections, with bound parameters I know I'm safe (as long as there is no dynamic sql generated under the hood)

Comment: be careful using hdbc placeholderes for updating/inserting. They have a nasty bug. They add an extra space at the end of the value. I fixed the bug on github https://github.com/hdbc/hdbc-odbc/pull/10 but it is still not accepted to main repository